# What's the best way to transfer a huge folder (4GB+) across Servers

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I need to transfer a dvd's worth of content in a folder - many small files, some big across servers on a consistent basis.

What's the best way of doing this?

This is for a windows server environment.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the bittorrent protocol.

Comment: Can you run it after hours without impacting the environment?

Comment: How about compressing the folder? Also, copying a single file is much faster than copying many smaller files.

Comment: additional requirements/limitations might help narrow the search...

Comment: 4+gb is hugh? My last folder upload wa 200gb and that was tiny.

Comment: 4gb feels like 400GB over a crappy wan link

Comment: Thanks! Currently I'm thinking zipping the folder somehow would be the best way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There any number of file transfer tools.  If you need a scheduled sync up of folders you might try [Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) or [Richcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog).  For a more pernament solution without having to script you might try setting up [DFS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732863%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 for Robocopy.  Something like Robocopy + compression would be a win here.

Comment: I mention robocopy just for completeness, it wouldn't be in my top 10 choices but lots of admins know it.

Comment: @JimB, are any of these scriptable? As in, could I easily interface with them using a Ruby script?

Comment: Yes both are scriptable,  I can't speak to ruby but you can do it in batch files, powershell, or vbscript.

Answer (score 2):

Given a professional setup (active directoy on both sides):

Establish a DFS-R replicated folder. I maintain this oneevery site allowing me nice background syncs between them. I transfer your amount pretty much daily.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most sophisticated way but easiest.

Set up a share with correct permissions and run the copy over night...........

That would be my, 'anything for an easy' life answer.

Or burn the DVD, and put into the destination drive, copy of the DVD....

Comment: I've found that the shared folder will fail sometimes (my use case was ~400gb over ~1.5 million files) - Windows just barfs on it before it transfers a single file.  FTP seems much more robust.